# JQuery same method is slowing down the browser

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a issue with JQuery ajax calls,the issues is like this:

If I use the same query multiple times in a row the browser starts to slow down with every time the method is used.Don't know how to say it right so I will put an example.

```
$("#categAdProdIes").on("change",function(){
    var categId=$("#categAdProdIes").val();
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:"php/facturi/prodAjax.php",
        data:{categId:categId}
    }).done(function(rez){
            $("#prodAdIes").html(rez);
        });
});
```

The method above(select menu which uses ajax to get options in another select menu), If I use it more then once in a row the page is getting slower and slower until it freezes.
The whole project is an web app with dynamic content(all is loaded via .ajax()).

Can someone tell me why is this problem appearing and how can I fix it?

Update #2:
I solved the issue but I do not understand why.
I have a button which makes the div containing the select element visible and I put the function inside that function and the problem is solved but I do not know why,so I can be aware in the future.

This is the function:

```
$("#badProdIes").on("click",function(){
        $(".adaugProdIesForm").css("display","block");
    });
```

And this is how it looks after the fix:

```
$("#badProdIes").on("click",function(){
    $(".adaugProdIesForm").css("display","block");
    $("#categAdProdIes").on("change",function(){
        var categId=$("#categAdProdIes").val();
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:"php/facturi/prodAjax.php",
            data:{categId:categId}
        }).done(function(rez){
                $("#prodAdIes").html(rez);
            });
    });
});
```

Comment: are you sure it's the actual browser freezing? what's task manager saying? if you're testing this locally, then it's possible PHP is in a loop, so it freezes your PC... also, it's possible that with a LOT of data, the `$("#prodAdIes").html(rez);` part would be able to bring your browser down to a crawl if done in some close successions

Comment: It is actually just the tab that has the page.It is not the pc,and the data loaded is not bigger then 10-20 lines of <option></option>.

Comment: must be something other than just this code then - have you tried a bit of [profiling](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/06/12/javascript-profiling-chrome-developer-tools/)? it would help discovering where the bottleneck really lies...

Comment: I have a update on my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem, so I will post it here in case someone is having the same proble.
It was simply because the functions were running under AjaxComplete and there were to many queries binded and solved it by using the `.off()` function like this :

```
$("#badProdIes").off().on("click",function(){
        $(".adaugProdIesForm").css("display","block");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly an ajax cache issue ..
Try:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the only thing I can think of at the moment, but if you are running this function a lot I would cache your selectors, even though you are using id's which is a good thing.

```
var select = $("#categAdProdIes");
var categId = $("#categAdProdIes");
var container = $("#prodAdIes");

select.on("change",function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:"php/facturi/prodAjax.php",
        data:{categId:categId.val();}
    }).done(function(rez){
        container.html(rez);
    });
});
```

Not sure how much of a performance boost that will give you but worth a try,

Comment: just read the comments above, if it's just `option`s that you are returning via ajax you can just append them to a `select` rather than replacing the html of an element, have you tried that?

Comment: But appending wouldn't just add more options to the select element?

Comment: yep, it does, if you are only returning `<option value=""></option>...` you can just append it to the select.